# Trouble changing link hover background-colour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This should be a simple thing to do, but I cant seem to change the hover `background-color` on the tweets on the following page:

http://www.studiopsk.com/news.html

All the other links are fine, but the ones on the latest tweets won't seem to change?

Using this to try...

```
<script>
    if(sessionStorage.getItem("visited") != "true"){
var colors = Array("#A3F8EF", "#FF7275", "#CBB6E7", "#FF9D74", "#FDF874"), idx;
idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length); // Pick random index
sessionStorage.setItem("colour", colors[idx]);
newColour = sessionStorage.getItem("colour");
}
newColour = sessionStorage.getItem("colour");

$("div.tweets_txt a").hover(function(){
  $(this).css("background-color", newColour+"!important");
}, function() {
  $(this).css("background-color","transparent");
});  
sessionStorage.setItem("visited", "true");
</script>
```

Comment: Are you attempting to change the color?  I only see where you change the background-color.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: why not use simple css?

Comment: @DanOrlovsky sorry yes that should be background color. Will edit question now

Comment: Oh, so you want the whole tweet box to change color on mouseover?

Comment: @DanOrlovsky - just the links in the tweets. If you hover over the other links on the site you can see the desired effect

Comment: OK, so you're TRYING to accomplish the effect of the link you provided?

This can easily be done in your CSS file using the :hover pseudo-class like so:
div.tweets_txt a:hover{ **insert styles here**}

Comment: @DanOrlovsky why not write an answer rather than a comment?

Comment: hi @DanOrlovsky - sorry Im probably not explaining this very well. On the page that I linked to, if you hover over the "our work" or "about" links under the logo for instance, the background colour changes to a specific color. If you hover over a link in one of the tweets though, it changes the background colour to the same colour as the text. They should all be the changing to the same color as the links in the nav bar

Comment: deleted my answer.  I checked the source code.  The class: tweets_txt is not assigned to any div, therefore, there is no style to be applied.

Comment: Yeah, upon further investigation, it doesn't look like the elements you are targeting exist on the page, therefore there is nothing to be styled.  The only thing I have left to suggest is to add: class="tweets_txt" to the div with the ID "tweecool"

Comment: hmm strange - I previously tried to target all links with $("a").hover(function(){ but that didnt work either

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what you're trying to accomplish, and I think just setting a class on the elements based on situation will make your life easier. But it appears that you're talking about the problem being for new elements added to the page, if that's the case, it appears that you are using javascript that's being executed in HTML, and not on any event, just on page load, which means it will only run once, at page load. And won't effect any elements added to the page dynamically at a later time.

Comment: yes I think it might be the problem that the style is being applied before the creation of the links? The script to create the twitter links is actually meant to wrap each one in a <div class="tweets_txt"> I think this should be able to be seen if you inspect element in the browser. If you have a look at the javascript javascripts/tweecool.min.js on the page it should hopefully show this.